# string with float (latitude, longituse) can not be cast as float - this shows 0

Tags: php, casting

I have a CSV with geodata. I have made a script that transforms this to a array ans saves it in the database. but i want to save the lat and long as a decimal. but for some strange reason as a string it shows a value but when i convert it to any type of float or decimail it shows 0?

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
$tmpName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$csvAsArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($tmpName));
array_shift($csvAsArray); //removes first
array_pop($csvAsArray); //removes last

foreach ($csvAsArray as $k=>$v) {
    $municipality = str_replace('"', "", $v[2]);
    $city = str_replace('"', "", $v[3]);
    $zip = str_replace('"', "", $v[4]);
    $lat = $v[5];
    $data = [
        'country' => $v[0],
        'province' => $v[1],
        'municipality' => $v[2],
        'city' => $v[3],
        'nl_fourpp' => $v[4],
        'lat' => $v[5],
        'lng' => $v[6],
        'date_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];

    var_dump($v[6]);  // THIS SHOWS: string(15) "4.91666"
    var_dump((float) $v[6]);  // THIS SHOWS: float(0)
    var_dump(floatval($v[6]));  // THIS SHOWS: float(0)
    var_dump(number_format($v[6]));  // THIS SHOWS: Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in
    //etc...

    //save the fields
    ...............
}
```

the data array looks like this (as you can see it shows the lat and the lng..... but when i convert it to a number it just shows 0 ?

```
    Array
(
    [country] => NL
    [province] => Noord-Holland
    [municipality] => Amsterdam
    [city] => Amsterdam
    [nl_fourpp] => 1000
    [lat] => 52.34999
    [lng] => 4.91666
    [date_created] => 2017-10-21 07:18:21
)
1
```

EDIT when i dump the var using symfonys var dumper i get `"\x005\x002\x00.\x003\x004\x009\x009\x009\x00"` but when i var dumpt it i get the "string" number

Comment: The source string seems to be encoded in some multibyte encoding. Adjust your locale settings to match the source file encoding with `setlocale()` function. As for the zero result of `floatval()`, the leading characters are not recognized as numbers (see [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok still dont know what the problem is but i fixed it by doing

```
    public function FixLatLngStr($str) {
    $x = explode("\x00", $str);
    array_shift($x); //removes first
    array_pop($x); //removes last
    return implode("",$x);
}
```

and this returns a "normal" float value

Answer (score 0):

change it

```
var_dump(number_format($v[6]));
```

to

```
var_dump(number_format((float)$v[6]));
```

Comment: as i said casting to float returns 0... zo this solution would also give a 0